# Unable to force 15:9 aspect ratio with modeline and xandr

Tags: display-resolution, modelines

I've got an 800x480 display running under Ubuntu 18.04.3LTS (within VirtualBox on Windows 10). The display is a square-pixel, 15:9 panel, but regardless of the modeline parameters and/or changes I make to xrandr, I cannot enforce this aspect ratio. I use the Universal Modeline Calculator (UMC) tool to generate the modeline, as it allows for additional options (namely the vertical-sync).

When I apply the custom resolution, the display aspect ratio appears 'squashed', with black bars above and below the actual Ubuntu window. I also note that once the custom resolution has been added via xrandr, the resolution displays as 800x480 (16:10) in the 'Screen Display' settings list.

Am I missing anything obvious, or is there anything else I can try?

Comment: You're likely missing the installation of guest additions.

Comment: I've just done an update, dist-upgrade and installed virtualbox guest additions, but it doesn't appear to have made any impact I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this issue. I ended up uninstalling my Nvidia drivers (in the Windows 10 host), installing the latest drivers, installing the correct, custom resolution in Windows, and then installing the custom resolution in Ubuntu (inside the VirtualBox VM).